# ChartJs com dataset dinamico

Tags: javascript, chartjs

Preciso criar um *dataset* dinamico onde os dados serão preenchido através de uma consulta no banco de dados, esses dados poderão gerar N barras a serem plotadas então o *dataset* precisa ser criado de acordo com as informações vindas do *DB*.

O número de barras criadas também depende da consulta.
Vai ficar assim:

```
Data 1-> barra 1
Data 2 -> barra 2
Data 3 -> barra 3
Data 1(horario diferente, mesmo ID) -> barra 4....
```

Estou usando o [chartsjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) para plotar.

Answer (score 1):

Crie um vetor com as informações retornadas no banco e inclua o vetor nos parâmetros do dataset.

```
var data[]; 
var valores[];
//data e valores virão do seu banco.

this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: "Nome do gráfico",
    datasets: [{                
        label:data,
        data: valores,
        backgroundColor: #00000,
        borderWidth: 0                
    }]
}
```